# GCC compiler is unable to find pcre.h

Tags: c, unix, freebsd, pcre

I am trying to compile a C program which uses regexes on FreeBSD. I have checked in /usr/local/include and the file pcre.h is definitely there.

However, no matter what I do, I get the following compiler error:

```
/usr/home/myname/project/include/pcre_wrap.h:4:18: error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
```

What could be going wrong? My understanding of C libraries on Unix could be better...

Comment: did you use "" or did you use <>?  You should use ""

Comment: I tried #include <pcre.h> and #include "/usr/local/include/pcre.h" and neither one worked.

Comment: If your project is in local, then only put "include/pcre.h", though, I think the full path shouldn't be a problem.  If you have the library, and you define it as a user defined library (with quotes, not <>), everything should be good.  You also  need pcre_wrap.h, not pcre.h; make sure you have that and its included

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comment above says you need to use #include. If this isn't working you may want to export an environment variable `C_INCLUDE_PATH` that points to the header file.

Failing that why not try adding `-I/usr/local/include` to your `gcc` call, something like `gcc myfile.c -I/usr/local/include -o myexe`

Comment: Works! (The $C_INCLUDE_PATH thing that is)

Answer (score 0):

I got a slightly different error when building a Golang module in M1 MacOS, `brew install pcre` only did not work for me.

> github.com/glenn-brown/golang-pkg-pcre/src/pkg/pcre
> ../../../../.gvm/pkgsets/go1.20/global/pkg/mod/github.com/glenn-brown/golang-pkg-pcre@v0.0.0-20120522223659-48bb82a8b8ce/src/pkg/pcre/pcre.go:52:10:
> fatal error: 'pcre.h' file not found
> #include <pcre.h>
> ^~~~~~~~ 1 error generated.

it can be solved by creating a symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/include /usr/local/include
```